# Accessing Swift dictionary using variable as key

Tags: swift, dictionary, skspritenode

Using SKSpriteKit's userData property, I have used the following line to attach x and y co-ordinates on a grid, to the node.

```
node.userData = ["x": x, "y": y]
```

I am then using `touchesBegan` to send the data to this function.

```
func touched(userData: NSDictionary) {
        print(userData)
   }
```

The console successfully prints the data required. Using this dictionary...

```
var dictionary: [AnyHashable : Any] = [1: "Test1",
                          2: "Test2",
                          3: "Test3",
                          4: "Test4",
                          5: "Test5",
                          6: "Test6",
                          7: "Test7"
]
```

I then want to retrieve the relevant key-pair using:

```
dictionary[userData["x"]]
```

However, I get the following error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type 'NSDictionary' with an index of type
>   'String'

Comment: Why are you using `NSDictionary` in Swift? Use a Swift dictionary with the proper types. Why is your `dictionary` variable declared with `AnyHashable` and `Any` when it should use `[Int:String]`?

Comment: To reiterate where rmaddy is going here, use of the `Any*` types and `NSDictionary` (which bridges to `Any*` types) is almost always going to cause you lots of casting problems and type-mismatches like this one. `Any` and its kin exist to deal with special cases (particularly bridging into ObjC). They're not general-purpose tools. Just use the types as they're intended (in this case `[Int: String]`) and the compiler will take care of the work for you.

Comment: I've tried to convert it, but SpriteKit's userData is given as NSDictionary instead of a native Swift dictionary. I've changed my dictionary variable to [Int:String], but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Are `x` and `y` integers? Or are they `CGFloat` or similar?

Comment: `x` and `y` are integers created by a for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic case of a misleading diagnostic due to `Any` casting.

Just to simplify the problem (and get rid of SpriteKit):

```
let userData: NSDictionary = ["x": 1, "y": 2]
let dictionary = [1: "Test1",
                  2: "Test2",
                  3: "Test3",
                  4: "Test4",
                  5: "Test5",
                  6: "Test6",
                  7: "Test7"
]
dictionary[userData["x"]]
```

The diagnostic is:

```
Cannot subscript a value of type 'NSDictionary' with an index of type 'String'
```

But that's not really the problem. The main problem is that `userData["x"]` returns an Optional (`Any?`). The Optional would always keep this from working. But `Any?` is also a bizarro-type that creates all kinds of problems for Swift. (Because `Any?` is itself `Any`, and `Any` can be trivially promoted into `Any?`. So `Any`, `Any?`, `Any??`, `Any???`, etc. are all somewhat interchangable types. It's a bit of a mess and creates a lot of confusion.)

The compiler goes looking for a subscript that takes a `String` and returns an `Int`, and can't find it. The rolls back to a diagnostic about `String` being the problem, which is a very, very roundabout way is true, but isn't what you were expecting.

You need to makes sure you have an `Int` here, and that it exists. As one example:

```
if let x = userData["x"] as? Int {
    dictionary[x] // "Test1"
}
```

Comment: Wondered if you could help, I've changed the data structure of `dictionary` to [Int:Int?]. Upon checking if the value of a key-pair in the dictionary is not nil using `if dictionary[x] != nil` and then finding out if the value of SK userData is the same as the value in key-pair using `if notes[x] == y`. I'm getting _Cannot subscript a value of type 'inout [Int : Int?]' (aka 'inout Dictionary<Int, Optional<Int>>')_

Comment: `notes[x]` in this case would be `Int??` (double Optional), if I'm understanding that `notes` is `[Int:Int?]`. It's very strange to have an optional value in a dictionary. Why not just not have the value? Key thing to remember is that dictionary subscripting always returns an optional. So in your `dictionary[x] != nil` case, this is highly ambiguous. You can wind up with `.some(nil)` as the value (which is not itself `nil`. Optional promoting might make that equality check work anyway, but it's a very tricky construct.)

Comment: I think (correct me if I'm wrong), I need an optional because sometimes, some of the values needs to be `nil`. If I change `notes` to [Int:Int], it throws an error message. I then have to condition check the dictionary to see if any of the notes are `nil`.

Comment: I don't understand what `notes` is in this case. Again, it's very strange to put optionals in a dictionary. If you don't want `x[1]` to have a value, then don't put a value at 1. Perhaps you should open a new question to address what you're running into. (In any case, you need to deal with the fact that `x[y]` returns a *optional* of the value type. So if the value type is `Int?`, `x[y]` is `Int??` and you have to unwrap it twice to get to the real value.)

Comment: I've solved this by putting a `0` in the dictionary, this has actually solved another problem I was having, so all good :)